# What observatory featured in the climax of "Northstar"?

Tags: real-location

*[Northstar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091650/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)* was a 1986 film starring Greg Evigan as Major Jack North, an astronaut who acquires superhuman powers whenever he is exposed to sunlight. At the climax of the film North fights the villains in an observatory — the plot device being that he is normal in the gloom of the observatory's dome, but can use his powers when he falls into the slit of light entering through the dome's shutter.

The observatory seemed to be authentic, and was on a snow-covered hill/mountain surrounded by scrubby pine trees. Does anyone know which observatory it was?

[image: Slightly blurry screenshot of two people seen from behind, one in a blue coat the other in a brown jacket, on a snow-covered hillside with a circular building crowned by a perfect white dome in the mid distance]

Frame from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xi23kQXoggI)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guessing from visual similarity and location only - Palomar Observatory.

[image: Mount Palomar Observatory, all in white, the dome standing out against a solid blue sky and the green grass and trees around it]

(image [source](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Palomar-Observatory))

In this frame from the film you can see the base of the scope cradled between the two diagonal cylindrical supports.

[image: Observatory interior from the movie showing the open framework holding the mirror and the diagonal members supporting it]

And in this picture as well

[image: Wide-angle picture of the interior of the observatory, showing the entire telescope and its supporting structure]

(Image [source](https://sites.astro.caltech.edu/palomar/about/telescopes/images/HaleTelescope2.jpg))

Screenshot from youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xi23kQXoggI)

Comment: Your answer came marginally (by a few seconds) before Buzz's, and you also include the nice interior detail, so I'll give the accept to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

That's the Mount Palomar Observatory, located north of San Diego (and thus relatively conveniently located for Hollywood filming).

[image: Mount Palomar Observatory]

It has a fairly distinctive appearance, with the rings running around the cylindrical base.